# Programmatically check whether the Java Development Kit is installed

Tags: java, c#, .net, registry

As part of an installer, I'm building, I want to check whether the Java Development Kit is installed already (specifically the JDK, the JRE will not do). On my local machine, I can clearly see the key in the registry (HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit), but the following code (C#) doesn't find said key:

```
RegistryKey jdkKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit");
```

When I investigate which keys are present under "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft", using the following code, the Java Development Kit is not there.

```
string[] keyNames = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft").GetSubKeyNames();
```

I've had a look at my environment variables programmatically, too, and nothing there seems to point to the JDK being present either (it is there, as I said above, it's in the registry, and I'm using it for Java development for the program I'm building an installer for, funnily enough).

Any ideas as to how I can determine whether the JDK is installed? As I say, the JRE alone will not suffice, as I'm doing some compilation at runtime, for which I need the JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was barking up the wrong (registry) tree. I hadn't realised that the registry root is dependent on the configuration platform of my application. Because my app's target platform was set to x86, all searches began in the Wow6432Node of my registry. Changing my target platform to "Any CPU" fixed this, and I can programmatically access all of the trees of my registry as they appear graphically in regedit.

It's possibly worth noting that I was using Visual C# 2010 Express to do this, so changing my target platform had to be done by directly editing the XML of my ".csproj" file, as there are no UI options to do this.

Comment: You should, if possible, mark you own answer as the answer.

Comment: I can't for another two days, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
```

if empty should not be installed

Comment: This is not quite what I'm after. I know the JRE is a prerequisite of the JDK, but if I'm installing my software on a machine that doesn't have either the JRE or the JDK, I can't do this.

Comment: you mean that you want to run a java program without JVM (??)

Comment: No, I want to install the JDK if neither the JDK or the JRE are already installed, so that I can then install and use my Java program.

Comment: so 'java.library.path' shoul works, did you try on a machine without jre?

Comment: I feel that you've misunderstood my question. I want to use C# to find out if the JDK is installed. I agree, it's easy to find out if the JDK is installed if the JRE is installed, but, I'm building a Windows Installer package to install my software. If there is no JRE, I can't use your code to check for the JDK, so I'll need to install the JRE. If I just use C# to check for the JDK, I can run the JDK installer to install both the JRE and the JDK.

Comment: I understood, in fact I wrote you 'java.library.path' as system property, that is compilation type indipendent, so you can check it through C#, PHP or whatever you need

Comment: No you can't. The "java.library.path" environment variable doesn't exist in C# - all environment variables are in upper case, for a start.

Comment: did you try with this? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME")

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the Java **Development** Kit on the machine, you could try to check for the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, which usually points to the installation root of the JDK.

```
string javaHome = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME");
if (javaHome == null)
    Console.WriteLine("JDK seems not to be present");
```

Comment: I have already this (I should have been more explicit when talking about environment variables in my original post), but javaHome was null. I can see other environment variables using <code>Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()</code>. Any ideas why this might be? I'm running Visual Studio as an Administrator, so I'd assume I have permissions to see all of my registry entries and environment variables.

Comment: Is the variable registered when you look into the environment variables in your system configuration? I mean, if you install the JDK, the JAVA_HOME variable should be created automatically.